# Check if the element is last in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am stored the list of elements in the list and I would like to create a if statement so I can compare a string with the list to see if the element is not matched.

Here is what I use:

```
self.EPG_Channel = 'Channel 5'
self.channel_str = ['BBC One, BBC Two, ITV, Channel 4, Channel 5']
```

I want to create something is like:

```
if not self.EPG_Channel == self.channel_str:
   print "You are not in the last element in the list"
else:
   print "You are in the list element in the list so let do nothing..."
```

I want to know how do you create a if statement to check the elements in the list with a string to see if the element is not in the last element in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to something like this:

```
self.EPG_Channel = 'Channel 5'
self.channel_str = ['BBC One, BBC Two, ITV, Channel 4, Channel 5']
if self.EPG_Channel == self.channel_str[-1]:   
    pass
```

Comment: Be careful, if list is empty an IndexError will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the last element with `self.channel_str[-1]` :)